# Static home page with "Blog" inside?

Tags: theme-development

I'd like to have a static home page and also have a link called "Blog" that lists posts in the "blog" category in chronological order.

Would the best way to do this just be to place code in archive.php and do a "switch case" on the category and do a loop on the posts?

Just looking for some options before I decide on a strategy and code the solution.

Comment: 213 questions...10 answers. Impressive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wp dashboard > 'Page' > add new > name it 'Home', publish

wp dashboard > 'Page' > add new > name it 'Blog', publish

wp dashboard > Reading Settings > 'Front page displays' select 'a static page' set 'Front page' to 'Home' page that you have added > set 'Posts page' to 'Blog' page that you should have added.

It doesn't seem like you need to create a 'Blog' category. Just let your new 'Blog' page display the posts loop, which will be your index.php theme file.

Comment: Absolutely correct. I'll just add: if you want to customize the the display of either the Front Page or the Blog Posts Index, create/modify `front-page.php` for the Front Page, and `home.php` for the Blog Posts Index.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll be doing it a bit differently (via script) but this helps clear up some questions I had about the default setup.